# MQL4 script to export data from History Center to csv file

Tags: mql4

Is there a MQL4 script to export data from History Center to csv file?
Is it possible to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to go to the History Center (F2), select a currency pair, a timeframe, and click on Export at the bottom. You are given the ability to save a csv of the data that MT4 has downloaded. To get more accurate data, I would rather download historical data from a reliable source such as Dukascopy (http://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/historical/)